# How can I throw "Shurikens"?

Tags: macos, shadow-fight-2

I'm at level 10 and buy "Shurikens" from store. I've [read](http://shadowfight.wikia.com/wiki/Shuriken) "Players can throw them by, pressing the I key" but I doesn't work.
How can I use Ranged Weapons?
If is important: I use OS X 10.10.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press the K key, not the key listed on the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>K</kbd> key works the best. It actually dosen't work well this is definitely the case if it is with an apple product.